# Bitmap from WebView Content does not appear

Tags: android, bitmap, webview

I try to make a Bitmap from a WebView in Android. But when I create a Bitmap from WebView, it is created but content does not appear (blank screen). I have also tried WebViewClient to display content after page has been finished. But content cannot be displayed. Is there anybody who knows the answer of this?

Thanks.

Comment: are you saving drawing cache of webview ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
MY_VEB_VIEW.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/images/", "<img src='MY_IMAGE.png' />",
                "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitm = ImageSelection.mWebView.getDrawingCache(true);
```

This works..but you will have blank space in bitmap if image is small..
The image viewed in webview is converted to bitmap.